# How to scroll window on particular div id

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is redirecting me end of the page.
But i want to load page on this **div** id.

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#win_'+ type).offset().top }, 'slow');   

<div class="panel panel-default" id="win_1"> </div>
```

Comment: Is your `type` is defined above i.e. `$('#win_'+ type)`. ?

Comment: Yes type giving id and merge with div id i.e win_1 (1 coming from TYPE).

Comment: Is there any error you are getting? Try using hard code id once. The syntax is absolutely correct.

Comment: No there is no error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Can you submit the complete code? I'm not sure what would you like to achieve.

> This is redirecting me end of the page. But i want to load page on
>   this div id.

There are many possibilities to load page on certain div element.

```
window.location.hash = '#win_1';

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#win_' + type).offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Another one is from this url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

```
var element = document.getElementById("win_1");

element.scrollIntoView();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Really strange that is not working on your side. It may happen that your code is clashing with other code. I checked on my side on multiple platforms, and on top on codepen and jsfiddle. I can not say why is not working at your side, if you do not submit more info with code examples. 
There is a good example from url below, that you can try:

https://gist.github.com/JosephSilber/3848811

```
// jQuery plugin to scroll to an element on the page
// Usage: $('#someElement').scrollTo();
//    or: $('#someElement').scrollTo(750); 

(function($)
{
    var $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document),
        $documentWrapper = $('body, html');

    $.fn.scrollTo = function ( speed )
    {
        if ( speed === undefined ) speed = 300;

        $documentWrapper.animate({
            scrollTop: Math.min( this.offset().top - 10, $document.height() - $window.height() )
        }, speed);

        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

$('#win_1').scrollTo();
```

Comment: i don't know what is wrong with it, no script is working on it. Please help (

Comment: Blackcoat77 , have you any other way to do it??

Comment: @neha910 Check update, and please provide more info about your code and idea behind, so that we can help you to solve your problem.